# Why are the components of elasticity tensor 21?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, symmetry, tensor-calculus, elasticity, stress-strain

I know there's a [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/643798/2451) but I didn't understand the whole [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/643800/168640) which was:

> **A 6×6 matrix has 36 different components. When you reduce it to a symmetric case it has 1+2+3+4+5+6=21, where we are summing the number of entries without double counting.**

I don't understand the sum from 1 to 6. What does it mean? Why do we do this sum?

Comment: Note that to do something like rotate the tensor to a different basis (say through Euler angles) you will need to consider the full 9x9 matrix. The 6x6 is a engineering shorthand, not a 'real' tensor.

Comment: Thanks @JonCuster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us call the matrix $L$ with components $L_{i,j}$ with $i,j\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

We want $L$ to be symmetric, i.e. $L_{i,j}=L_{j,i}$.

First let us fix all $L_{1,j}$ to some arbitrary value (we have 6 of those).
Now for $L_{2,j}$ you fix all components except $L_{2,1}=L_{1,2}$ that was already fixed.
Continue this pattern until you get to $L_{6,j}$, which has all values already decided by the previous steps except for $L_{6,6}$. Thus we get $6+5+4+3+2+1$ variables that you can freely choose and keep the matrix symmetric.

Alternatively, another way to see it, it is to count all the components of $L$ in the upperdiagonal.
You have 1 corner ($L_{1,6}$), 2 components in the diagonal next to the corners ($L_{1,5}$,$L_{2,6}$),$\cdots$, and 6 in the main diagonal ($L_{i,i}$). Try to find other ways to count them (in black):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
L_{11} &L_{12} & L_{13} & L_{14} & L_{15}  & L_{16 }  \\
\color{red}{L_{12}} &L_{22} & L_{23} & L_{24} & L_{25}  & L_{26 }\\
\color{red}{L_{13}} &\color{red}{L_{23}} & L_{33} & L_{34} & L_{35}  & L_{36 } \\
\color{red}{L_{14}} &\color{red}{L_{24}} &\color{red}{L_{34}} & L_{44} & L_{45}  & L_{46 } \\
\color{red}{L_{15}} &\color{red}{L_{25}} &\color{red}{L_{35}} & \color{red}{L_{45}} & L_{55}  & L_{56 } \\
\color{red}{L_{16}} &\color{red}{L_{26}} &\color{red}{L_{36}} & \color{red}{L_{46}} & \color{red}{L_{56}}  & L_{66 }
\end{pmatrix}$$